# Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX) for System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I have a part of code which tries to export data (from database) to Excel. When I am trying to perform this task, it is generating this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
Additional information: Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
```

Code which is generating this error:

```
string ExcelFileName = RootFolder + "\\" + "Work_Sheet.xls";
File.Copy(RootFolder + "\\" + "WorksOrder_Template.xls", ExcelFileName);
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
xlWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName, 0, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, false, true, Type.Missing);
Excel.Worksheet Page2;
Excel.Worksheet Page3;
Page2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet2");
Page3 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet3");
```

The code line on :

```
Page3 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet3");
```

is generating the aforementioned error. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: ...is there actually a "Sheet3" in the Excel file?

Comment: yes. I also worked it out. Since there was a migration in program reports (WorksOrder_Template.xls), the 'Sheet3' was missing from the report file unfortunately. After adding the Sheet3 to that file, the program started working properly.

Comment: I upped your question.... Don't know who marked it down as this is a big issue and NO ONE seems to be able to give a clear explanation of what's going wrong... I am also getting this error message when trying to create relationships, but I can do it manually, but not in code... Even though I have another method which CAN add relationships no problem, I copied that code, edited it and now it won't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Sheet3" was missing from WorksOrder_Template.xls file and hence, when the code tried to fetch the 'Sheet3' it generated the error.